# Show and Hide ContextMenu with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

As shown in the HTML below, there is a contextmenu with `id=contextmenu-node.`
Since the model `isVisible` is not define before, the context menu is invisible. 
At my directive `ng-contextmenu`, I watch the right click to the text 
`Right Click On the Item!` and when right clicked, I update isVisible to `true` and I expect the `contextmenu-node` to be visible. However, it never shows up.

What shall be the problem?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaprak/5Lk2V/2/) of my question.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul id="contextmenu-node" ng-show="isVisible">
        <li> Item 1 </li>
        <li> Item 2 </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-contextmenu> Right Click On the Item! </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

myApp.controller( "MainCtrl", [ "$scope", function($scope) {
    console.log("Main Controller loaded.");
}]);

myApp.directive( "ngContextmenu", function(){
    contextMenu = {};
    contextMenu.restrict = "AE";
    contextMenu.scope = {"isVisible": "="};
    contextMenu.link = function( lScope, lElem, lAttr ){
        lElem.on("contextmenu", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("Element right clicked.");
            lScope.isVisible = true;
        });
        lElem.on("mouseleave", function(e){
            console.log("Leaved the div");
            lScope.isVisible = false;
        });
    };
    return contextMenu;
});
```

CSS:

```
#contextmenu-node{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass variable to context menu and after its modified apply the changes. In the markup below you pass the isVisible to the directive

```
<div ng-contextmenu  visible="isVisible"> Right Click On the Item! </div>
```

and in the directive itself you just apply the changes

```
lElem.on("contextmenu", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();            
                console.log("Element right clicked.");
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                     $scope.visible = true;
                })
        });
```

Here is jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nawrockim/5Lk2V/10/

The problem in your code is that even though you define scope you dont pass the variable to the directive

One more thing: hiding ctx menu on mouseleave( of caption element) is not best idea - it will prevent you from going into menu - when you try it will disappear.

Comment: the `mouseleave` thing is not a problem if you stick the list inside the div.

Comment: How does `visible=isVisible` works? What is `visible` here? How does this attribute defined?

Comment: See "Here is jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nawrockim/5Lk2V/10/" for implementation - just a variable on scope -  contextMenu.scope = {"visible": "="};

Comment: marcinn, I have one more question: In this solution, as you also mentioned, when I leave the caption element, the context menu will disappear. So how can I stick the context menu inside a div?

Comment: Jorg, how can I stick the list inside the div? Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You're mistake is not applying scope in the directive:

```
 lScope.$apply(function () {
     lScope.$parent.isVisible = true;
 });
```

And the same for `false`. In the fiddle I'm also getting it directly of the $parent scope instead of local. This way you're tying a directive to controller scope though so it wont work as a stand alone type thing. Perhaps someone else has a better method.

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/5Lk2V/12/

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.directive( "ngContextmenu", function(){
    contextMenu = {};
    contextMenu.restrict = "AE";
    contextMenu.scope = {"isVisible": "="};
    contextMenu.link = function( lScope, lElem, lAttr ){
        lElem.on("contextmenu", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("Element right clicked.");
            lScope.isVisible = true;
        });
        lElem.on("mouseleave", function(e){
            console.log("Leaved the div");
            lScope.isVisible = false;
        });
    };
    return contextMenu;
});
```

You have isolated scope on your direcive.!! So, pass the argument with the same name that you are capturing in the scope: i.e.: **is-visible = "isVisible"**

```
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <ul id="contextmenu-node" ng-show="isVisible">
            <li> Item 1 </li>
            <li> Item 2 </li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-contextmenu is-visible="isVisible"> Right Click On the Item! </div>
    </div>
```